# R: Error al procesar JSON, data contiene objeto o array

Tags: java, json, eclipse

Al intentar procesar un json, dependiendo de la llamada que haga al servidor, este me devuelve un objeto el cual contiene el nodo data, si es uno solo este esta como objeto pero si son varios se muestran como array como puedo comprobar si el data es un array o un objeto para poder llamar a una clase u otra.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "client": "PAL",
        "organization": "*",
        "organization_info": {
            "name": "*",
            "searchKey": "0",
            "id": "0"
        },
        "id": "*****",
        "searchKey": "AJ23",
        "commercialName": "MANOLO",
        "fiscalName": "MANOLO",
        "locations": [{
                "address": "NUEVA",
                "city": "SEVILLA",
                "zipCode": "00000",
                "country": "ES"}]
    },
    {
        "client": "LAC",
        "organization": "*",
        "organization_info": {
            "name": "*",
            "searchKey": "0",
            "id": "0"
        },
        "id": "*****",
        "searchKey": "0ASD13",
        "commercialName": "DANI",
        "fiscalName": "DANI",
        "locations": [{
                "address": "FONTANA",
                "city": "VALLADOLID",
                "zipCode": "00000",
                "country": "ES"
            }]
    }]
```

Este es el JSON con array en el nodo data, pero en el siguiente obtengo un objeto al ser un solo resultado

```
{
"data": {
    "client": "PAL",
        "organization": "*",
        "organization_info": {
            "name": "*",
            "searchKey": "0",
            "id": "0"
        },
        "id": "*****",
        "searchKey": "AJ2",
        "commercialName": "MANOLO",
        "fiscalName": "MANOLO",
        "locations": [
                "address": "NUEVA",
                "city": "SEVILLA",
                "zipCode": "00000",
                "country": "ES"}]
   }
```

}

La idea de la clase Data es que sea generica para poder llamar a distintas clases Cliente, Proveedor, etc desde la clase main.

```
public class Data<T> {
private final T data;
private String link;

public Data(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
//get and set method



public class Cliente {
private String client;
private String organization;
private Org_info organization_info;
private String id;
private String fiscalName;
private String searchKey;
private String commercialName;
private String phone;
private String email;
private ArrayList<Locations> locations;



public Cliente(Org_info organization_info, String client, String organization, String id, String fiscalName, String searchKey,String phone, String email,
        String commercialName,ArrayList<Locations> locations) {
    super();
    this.organization_info=organization_info;
    this.client = client;
    this.organization = organization;
    this.id = id;
    this.fiscalName = fiscalName;
    this.searchKey = searchKey;
    this.commercialName = commercialName;
    this.locations = locations;

}
//get and set method
```

Como puedo hacer para poder almacenar tanto una lista como un objeto data, siendo la clase data generica para todos los json que pase.
Pero tengo como problema que el data puede ser un objeto o un array como se puede ver en los json de arriba

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, IOException {
    conection();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = br.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    String output = sb.toString();

    final Type tipoEnvoltorioCliente = new TypeToken<Data<Cliente>>(){}.getType();
        final Data<Cliente> envoltorioEmpleado = new Gson().fromJson(output, tipoEnvoltorioCliente);
```

Comment: Sería mejor que todo lo tratara como una lista de Data (List<Data>), cuando reciba la respuesta valide si la lista tiene un objeto o varios objetos.

Comment: No entiendo exactamente como dices, la idea es que data sea una clase generica y pueda usarla con una peticion json que me retorne clientes, proveedores, etc para yo luego poder renombrar los nombres de los campos desde sus respectivas clases. Acabo de actualizar el codigo para que sea generica pero no sabria como usarla tanto con una lista data como con un objeto data .

Comment: Creo que lo que necesita implementar es "Herencia en Json" de esta forma tiene usted una clase wrapper que por dentro tiene Data que puede ser Cliente, Proveedor o lo qe sea que extienda de Data. Verifique este enlace https://refactorizando.com/serializacion-y-deserializacion-en-herencia-con-jackson/ espero sea de su ayuda